# How to zoom Camera using android camera2 api with a float numbers

Tags: android

I developed a custom camera using `camera2 api`, i make zoom in and zoom out feature like this.

```
Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
int value = params.getMaxZoom();
params.setZoom(value);
```

It works for me, but how can I zoom camera by float number like 2.4f ?

Can any one help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getMaxZoom()

> Sets current zoom value. If the camera is zoomed (value > 0), the actual picture size may be smaller than picture size setting.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setZoom(int)

setZoom takes an Integer (whole number) so you can't set the zoom to a float.

---

The newest Android CameraX api's can Zoom using a Rect: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/Preview.html#zoom(android.graphics.Rect) (but under the hood it relies on Camera2 so I wouldn't hold out much hope for hardware float zoom.